# JSON values are being logged but aren't being displayed in the UI

Tags: reactjs, json, get

I am trying to display some JSON values in the UI. The issue I am running into is the JSON values I am grabbing are not being displayed in the UI.

```js
    const [userAliasSearchQuery, setUserAliasSearchQuery] = useState("")
    //build request params based on filter params
    const buildApiParams = () => {
      return {
        params: {
          user_login: "my_login"
        },
      }
    };
  
    const apiParams = useMemo(() => {
      return buildApiParams(props);
    }, [props.presentState]);

    const { response, error, isLoading } = useMakeRequest(
      GET_INFO,
      apiParams
  );
    const pagerInformationRows = (pagerResponse) => {

      const pagerInformation = Object.values(pagerResponse)
      console.log(pagerResponse)
      const rows = Object.values(pagerInformation).map((value) => {
        Object.values(value).map((jsonValues) => {
          console.log(jsonValues['audit_reference_id'])
          console.log(jsonValues['subject'])
          console.log(jsonValues['leader_alias'])
          console.log(jsonValues['exclude_user'])
          console.log(jsonValues['regions'])
          console.log(jsonValues['exclusion_days'])
          console.log(jsonValues['escalation'])
          console.log(jsonValues['job_family'])
          console.log(jsonValues['email_body'])
          console.log(jsonValues['creation_date'])
          console.log(jsonValues['created_by'])
          console.log(jsonValues['updated_date'])
          console.log(jsonValues['updated_by'])

          return (
            <>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['audit_reference_id']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['subject']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['leader_alias']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['exclude_user']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['regions']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['exclusion_days']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['escalation']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['job_family']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['email_body']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['creation_date']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['created_by']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['updated_date']}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{jsonValues['updated_by']}</TableCell>
            </>
          )
        })
        console.log(rows)
      })
      return rows;
    }
```

```
  return (
      <>
        <Column type="outline" spacingInset="400">
          {error && (
            <ToastFactory message={GENERIC_REQUEST_FAILURE_ERROR} type="error" />
          )}
          {isLoading && <Loader type="linear" size="small" />}
          {response ? (
            <>
            <SearchField value={userAliasSearchQuery} onChange={setUserAliasSearchQuery} placeholder="Search for an alias..."></SearchField>
              <Table headerRows={1}>
                  <TableRow>
                      <TableCell>Audit Reference Id</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Subject</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Leader Alias</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Exclude User</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Regions</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Exclusion Days</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Excalation</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Job Family</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Email Body</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Audit Expiration</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Creation Date</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Created By</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Updated Date</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>Updated By</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>

                  <TableRow>
                    {pagerInformationRows(response.data)}
                  </TableRow>

              </Table>
            </>
          ) : null}
        </Column>
      </>
    );
```

This is the current code I am using, I did notice one thing that my rows variable that was is being logged as undefined, even though I am passing the the api response into the variable.